# How do I add Gyroscope, Accelerometer, Euler, and Temperature data to one Arduino board?

Tags: arduino-uno, bno055

I have to use a BNO055 to get temperature/accelerometer/Euler/Gyroscope data into one Arduino board for a school project. I am very new to coding so I am not familiar with the commands. I have gotten my BNO055 to give me all the data individually but I am having problems getting them all compiled into one code file to upload. I have googled it but I keep getting links to upload them individually. Posted below is my latest attempt.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BNO055.h>
#include <utility/imumaths.h>

Adafruit_BNO055 bno = Adafruit_BNO055(55);

void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Orientation Sensor Test"); Serial.println("");

  /* Initialise the sensor */
  if (!bno.begin())
  {
    /* There was a problem detecting the BNO055 ... check your connections */
    Serial.print("Ooops, no BNO055 detected ... Check your wiring or I2C ADDR!");
    while (1);
  }

  delay(1000);

  bno.setExtCrystalUse(true);
}

void loop(void)
{
  /* Get a new sensor event */
  sensors_event_t event;
  bno.getEvent(&event);

  /* Display the current temperature */
  int8_t temp = bno.getTemp();

  Serial.print("Current Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.println(" Celsius");
  Serial.print("");
}

void loop(void)
{
  /* Get a new Sensor event */
  sensors_event_t event;
  bno.getEvent(&event);

  imu::Vector<3> gyroscope = bno.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_GYROSCOPE);

  /* Display the floating point data */
  Serial.print("X: ");
  Serial.print(gyroscope.x());
  Serial.print(" Y: ");
  Serial.print(gyroscope.y());
  Serial.print(" Z: ");
  Serial.print(gyroscope.z());
  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);
}

void loop(void)
{
  /* Get a new sensor event */
  sensors_event_t event;
  bno.getEvent(&event);

  imu::Vector<3> accelerometer = bno.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_ACCELEROMETER);

  /* Display the floating point data */
  Serial.print("X: ");
  Serial.print(accelerometer.x());
  Serial.print(" Y: ");
  Serial.print(accelerometer.y());
  Serial.print(" Z: ");
  Serial.print(accelerometer.z());
  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);
}

void loop(void)
{
  /* Get a new sensor event */
  sensors_event_t event;
  bno.getEvent(&event);

  imu::Vector<3> euler = bno.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_EULER);

  /* Display the floating point data */
  Serial.print("X: ");
  Serial.print(euler.x());
  Serial.print(" Y: ");
  Serial.print(euler.y());
  Serial.print(" Z: ");
  Serial.print(euler.z());
  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: why can't you do all that inside one `loop()` ... you already have multiple statements inside `loop()`, just add more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the code below work? I have no compiler at hand, so I can not test it.

If you have to explain what you have done, you'll get into trouble. I don't know your teacher, but ... ;-). Seriously, that was very basic stuff. Try to find some documentation, how to program with the Arduino IDE and learn the basics. A good startpoint is https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage .

Then go on with SENSORs and Vector Maths.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BNO055.h>
#include <utility/imumaths.h>

Adafruit_BNO055 bno = Adafruit_BNO055(55);

void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Orientation Sensor Test"); Serial.println("");

  /* Initialise the sensor */
  if (!bno.begin())
  {
    /* There was a problem detecting the BNO055 ... check your connections */
    Serial.print("Ooops, no BNO055 detected ... Check your wiring or I2C ADDR!");
    while (1);
  }

  delay(1000);

  bno.setExtCrystalUse(true);
}

void loop(void)
{
  /* Get a new sensor event */
  sensors_event_t event;
  bno.getEvent(&event);

  /* Display the current temperature */
  int8_t temp = bno.getTemp();

  Serial.print("Current Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.println(" Celsius");
  Serial.print("");

  imu::Vector<3> gyroscope = bno.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_GYROSCOPE);

  /* Display the floating point data */
  Serial.print("X: ");
  Serial.print(gyroscope.x());
  Serial.print(" Y: ");
  Serial.print(gyroscope.y());
  Serial.print(" Z: ");
  Serial.print(gyroscope.z());
  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);

  imu::Vector<3> accelerometer = bno.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_ACCELEROMETER);

  /* Display the floating point data */
  Serial.print("X: ");
  Serial.print(accelerometer.x());
  Serial.print(" Y: ");
  Serial.print(accelerometer.y());
  Serial.print(" Z: ");
  Serial.print(accelerometer.z());
  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);

  imu::Vector<3> euler = bno.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_EULER);

  /* Display the floating point data */
  Serial.print("X: ");
  Serial.print(euler.x());
  Serial.print(" Y: ");
  Serial.print(euler.y());
  Serial.print(" Z: ");
  Serial.print(euler.z());
  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My teacher only told us what to do, since classes are online he has been pretty lazy, he did not give us any references to look at so thank you for the link also. Sorry for the basic question lol im a petroleum engineering student so I am way out of my comfort zone with coding. And your code worked. I could not thank you enough for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Generally, I do not handle the homework for others. But you were honest and told us about the background. I also know from students in my neighbourhood how studying works these days. I'm seriously concerned about that. I'm from Germany - guessing by your name I would expect you are an irish man, so it seams, other countries have the same problems. Knowledge and Education are such precious assets, we should not waste them. I'm glad, I could help you.